# Does the Pathfinder Cat animal companion get minus AC and Atk Roll for being large?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, animal-companions

Here's what the SRD says for Cat, Big

> Starting statistics: Size Medium; Speed 40 ft.; AC +1 natural armor; Attack bite (1d6), 2 claws (1d4); Ability Scores Str 13, Dex 17, Con 13, Int 2, Wis 15, Cha 10; Special Attacks rake (1d4); Special Qualities low-light vision, scent.
>
> 7th-level advancement: Size Large; AC +2 natural armor; Attack bite (1d8), 2 claws (1d6); Ability Scores Str +8, Dex –2, Con +4; Special Attacks grab, pounce, rake (1d6).

It doesn't mention anything about minuses (AC/Atk Roll) when it gets the 7th level advancement. Does this imply it doesn't get bonus in cmb and cmd?

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, the creature gets bonuses/penalties for being Large

The size bonuses to AC, attack and CMB/CMD (and space/reach) are a standard that apply equally to all creatures.

It does list those minuses and pluses, as "Size Large"; that includes all the standard bonuses and penalties of being large.

Note that the stat blocks don't include "final" statistics like attack bonuses and AC, but only those base statistics needed to calculate the others. For example, it doesn't list that AC goes down by 1 because of the reduction in Dex when becoming large, because that is the standard result of Dex being reduced by 2 points.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I was on the same direction about it and just wanted some other opinion. Thanks again.